# Understand Scrapy Debug information

Tags: scrapy

I would like to get an understanding of what the line means by the word **referer** in the following line while doing a scrapy run

```
2021-01-05 19:08:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/services/eaton-ups-and-battery-training/ups-first-responder-training/eaton-9315-training.html> (referer: https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/sitemap.html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scrapy, if you first yield a Request to say `example.com` then in the parse function of that request you yield another request to say `google.com` then scrapy will automatically add a `referer` header from the page you came from. This is to simulate how a browser works. It's just telling the server which site you came from.

You can disable this in `settings.py` with `REFERER_ENABLED = False`

Comment: Will the scrapper not visit other websites if "REFERER_ENABLED" is disabled??

Comment: It will, it just won't send that header alone to tell the server where it came from.